# Grinding stone: Can a surface be ground without a harder material?

Tags: condensed-matter, friction

Proponents of unorthodox Egyptology ideas use the argument that some specific culture can not have created flat surfaces with the smoothness quality of a specific example artifact.

The idea is that a harder material is needed to grind a surface, and there was no harder material available at the time to build grinding tools.

That argument has been used regarding granite.

I expect it to be false, because grinding a surface should be possible by rubbing two surfaces on each other with particles in between them, all three of the same material.

Is it true that smooth surfaces can not be created without a harder material?

Answer (score 2):

"Is it true that smooth surfaces can not be created without a harder material?" - no.

Look up how diamonds are polished - the polishing surface is another diamond or diamond dust.

Comment: How should I understand this? The two sentences seems to contradict each other

Comment: @Icv I'm not sure where you see a contradiction. You *don't* need a harder material to create a smooth polished surface. A demonstration of this is diamond polishing, where one diamond is used to polish another diamond. In the same way, ancient Egyptians could have used one piece of granite to polish another, even if no harder substance was available to them.

Comment: You're right. I interpreted harder as "$\ge$" (that's is harder or as equally hard)

Comment: Let me specify: would a *less* hard material work (for polishing)?